# How does a client get an SSL certificate from an ActiveMQ Broker?

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic

I have an ActiveMQ Broker living on AWS. I'm trying to secure connections from clients using SSL. I have set up the broker to use SSL, but I don't quite understand where the clients are supposed to get the certificate from. Do I need to copy the cert from the broker and package it with client code? Or do I remotely retrieve the cert programmatically each time the client is launched?

Relevant SSL Setup in `activemq.xml`

```
<sslContext> 
    <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.base}/conf/broker.ks"
      keyStorePassword="password" trustStore="file:${activemq.base}/conf/broker.ts"
      trustStorePassword="password"/>
```

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61714?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

The clients connecting will be Java clients using JMS. At this point I'm using the default cert that comes packaged with the ActiveMQ installation.

Comment: I've added the relevant ssl configurations from the broker to the original post. The clients connecting will be Java clients using JMS. At this point I'm using the default cert that comes packaged with the ActiveMQ installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html) states:

> ActiveMQ includes key and trust stores that reference a dummy self signed cert. When you create a broker certificate and stores for your installation, either overwrite the values in the conf directory or delete the existing dummy key and trust stores so they cannot interfere)

Therefore, you should delete the existing `broker.ks` and `broker.ts` and create new ones for your installation. You've got a couple of options here.

I imagine that AWS has some sort of infrastructure to acquire SSL certificates and that those certificates would be signed by a well-known certificate authority which would be trusted implicitly by your JMS clients. A quick search turned up [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/).

However, you also have the option of using a "self-signed" certificate which is, by definition, *not* signed by a well-known certificate authority and therefore must be explicitly trusted by your clients.

You can take the self-signed route by using the following commands:

1. Using `keytool` (from the JDK), create a certificate for the broker:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias broker -keyalg RSA -keystore broker.ks
   ```
2. Export the broker's certificate so it can be shared with clients:

   ```
   keytool -export -alias broker -keystore broker.ks -file broker_cert
   ```
3. Create a certificate/keystore for the client:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keystore client.ks
   ```
4. Create a truststore for the client, and import the broker's certificate. This establishes that the client "trusts" the broker:

   ```
   keytool -import -alias broker -keystore client.ts -file broker_cert
   ```

When starting the client's VM, specify the following system properties:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/client.ts
```

If you choose the self-signed route then you only need to generate the client.ts once and then copy that to every client. The clients will use the same truststore every time they connect (assuming the broker's certificate doesn't change).